# How can I get tree result of random forest in h2o?

Tags: random-forest, h2o

I am using random forest in h2o.
But I don't understand the meaning of the parameters in the returned result.
This is my original data.
[image]

I would have liked to see results like this:
(I set number of trees = 3 and response column = "Play".)

```
tree1:
Wind = false: yes {no=0, yes=6}
Wind = true
|   Temperature > 77.500: no {no=2, yes=0}
|   Temperature ≤ 77.500: yes {no=1, yes=5}

tree2:
Humidity > 92.500: no {no=3, yes=0}
Humidity ≤ 92.500: yes {no=2, yes=9}

tree3:
Wind = false: yes {no=0, yes=6}
Wind = true
|   Temperature > 77.500: no {no=2, yes=0}
|   Temperature ≤ 77.500: yes {no=1, yes=5}
```

But I got a model contains many parameters but results.
This is my code and the results I got:

```
    DRFParametersV3 drfParams = new DRFParametersV3();
    drfParams.trainingFrame = H2oApi.stringToFrameKey("train");
    drfParams.validationFrame = H2oApi.stringToFrameKey("test");
    drfParams.ntrees=3;
    System.out.println("drfParams: " + drfParams);

    ColSpecifierV3 responseColumn = new ColSpecifierV3();
    responseColumn.columnName = ATT_LABEL_GOLF;
    drfParams.responseColumn = responseColumn;
    System.out.println("About to train DRF. . .");

    DRFV3 drfBody = h2o.train_drf(drfParams);
    System.out.println("drfParams: " + drfBody);

    JobV3 job = h2o.waitForJobCompletion(drfBody.job.key);
    System.out.println("DRF build done.");

    ModelKeyV3 modelKey = (ModelKeyV3)job.dest;
    ModelsV3 models = h2o.model(modelKey);
    System.out.println("models: " + models);
    System.out.println("models'size: " + models.models.length);

    DRFModelV3 model = (DRFModelV3)models.models[0];
    System.out.println("new DRF model: " + model);
```

And the result "DRFModelV3" is so confused. Where is the "forest" build by h2o?
[image]

Comment: this question is very similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37017165/r-plot-trees-from-h2o-randomforest-and-h2o-gbm. you can also take a look at this blog  post: https://aichamp.wordpress.com/2017/09/27/visualizing-h2o-gbm-and-random-forest-mojo-models-trees-in-python/

Comment: But I don't need to plot it, so I wouldn't use some plot util class in h2o. I need to build a "tree" in java by myself, so I need the data of drf results generated by h2o. I am still not understanding how to get the real data in the "model" in h2o.

Comment: Do you have any example in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One options is to download the MOJO, load it and use function `_computeGraph` on the MOJO object. Take a look at the H2O github [repo](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3) to learn from the code.

please also take a look at the documentation on the POJOs and MOJOs [here](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/productionizing.html)

Here some additional code that might help: https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/43f8ab952a69a8bc9484bd0ffac909b6e3e820ca/h2o-algos/src/test/java/hex/XValPredictionsCheck.java#L59-L69

Comment: PS: as you said in https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/43f8ab952a69a8bc9484bd0ffac909b6e3e820ca/h2o-algos/src/test/java/hex/XValPredictionsCheck.java#L59-L69 , I can't do this. Because hex.tree package cannot be found.  You can see my code below, I got a model "DRFModelV3", how can I use it to get a MOJO ?

Comment: Yes, Using "SharedTreeGraph g = ((DrfMojoModel) genModel)._computeGraph(treeToPrint);" can get a tree.